# why `su - test; mkdir ~/cc` does not create cc directory in test's home directory?

Tags: linux

`su - test; mkdir ~/cc` creates `cc` directory under root's home directory.

Why doesn't it create `cc` under test's home directory?

Comment: I'm actually surprised this works at all and doesn't hang in the subshell, but suspect the mkdir is likely executed only once the subshell exits and is thus executed as root.

Comment: In addition to the other things wrong with this, `~` is replaced with `$HOME` by the shell BEFORE the shell runs any commands, so it's already `/root/cc`, not `~/cc`, before mkdir is even started.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I think expansion is not performed on each command until the previous command has finished. You can test this out with wildcard expansion.

Comment: @MattMcNabb, that's true, but it doesn't matter -- when `su` exits, we're back to the original user, so if you fixed the other problems (by, say, running `sudo -u test mkdir ~/cc`), you'd hit the problem I described, because you'd be running mkdir as the test user, but with the filename `/root/cc`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you REALLY want to do is

```
su - test -c 'mkdir ~/cc'
```

What you're doing isn't going to work as the ; and the command after it will be evaluated by the same instance of bash that will take care of the su - part as Chris pointed out in his comment.

Answer (score 0):

`su` starts a new shell. The command doesn't terminate until the other shell exits; at which point the next command is processed.

You should be seeing that `cc` is not actually created until you exit from the `su` shell. (This is how POSIX-compliant shells work).

Comment: Not just bash -- any POSIX-compliant shell.

Answer (score -1):

Because when you run su test, you are not cd'd to their home directory. if you ran

```
su test -c "mkdir ~/cc"
```

it should work. I have had issues with that one as well.

Comment: Unlikely as the attempted command does not depend on the working directory.

Comment: This answer is wrong.

Comment: This has now been edited to no longer be incorrect. It is, however, now a duplicate.